# Cannot access foreign table using Postgres FDW

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, database-permissions, foreign-data-wrapper

I had a foreign table set up in Postgres 10. The role "role1" has been granted usage on the foreign server (fs) that was set up using the `postgres` superuser.

I imported the table using the import schema command:

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA f_schema LIMIT TO (my_fdw_table) FROM fs INTO ls;
```

That worked fine.

However, when I try to query the table I get the following error:

```
SELECT * FROM my_fdw_table LIMIT 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for view my_fdw_table
CONTEXT:  remote SQL command: ...
```

My understanding is that FDW should treat views and tables the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the remote user that you used in the *user mapping* for your local user and the foreign server does not have the required permissions on the table (or the schema that contains it).

Answer (score 0):

User "role1" should create user mapping for itself like:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR role1 SERVER fs OPTIONS (USER 'role1', PASSWORD 'password1');
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA f_schema LIMIT TO (my_fdw_table) FROM SERVER fs INTO ls;
```

Also, if "role1" is not an owner of the database, it should get access from its owner:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ls TO role1;
```

Assuming `ls` is local schema.